# File upload whit playwright change name on file (setInputFiles)

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, playwright

I'm moving e2e tests from cypress to playwright but have a problem. In cypress you can rename the file on upload but I can not find that you can do this with playwright. Dose anyone know it this is possible?

The system I am testing needs to have unique files so I need to rename the file to upload it.

Playwright:

```
await page.locator('input[type=file]').setInputFiles('../image.png');
```

Cypress:

```
cy.fixture('../image.png', { encoding: null }).as('testImage');
cy.get('input[type=file]').selectFile(
 {
    contents: '@testImage',
    fileName: mediaFileName,
    lastModified: Date.now(),
  },
  { force: true },
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this also in playwright. `setInputFiles` https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-set-input-files
supports object with name/type/buffer.

Here is an example how to do it.

```
test('should do upload file with different name.', async ({page}, testInfo) => {
    await page.goto('https://tmpfiles.org/');

    const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync('dummy.test.txt')
    const uploadInput = page.locator('input[name=\'file\']');
    const newFileName= '1234abc.txt'
    await uploadInput.setInputFiles({buffer: fileBuffer, name: newFileName, mimeType: 'text/plain'});

    const uploadBtn = page.locator('input[name=\'upload\']')
    await uploadBtn.click();
});
```

The property `name` that you provide will be used for file upload.